# AWS "Concurrent executions" vs "Burst concurrency" quota

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, quota

I am getting a bit confused by the above concepts when taking the default quota numbers into the picture.

So the default quota for "Concurrent executions" is 1000 and for "Burst concurrency" is 500 - 3000 region dependent.

Is that correct to say that for US West region which has a 3000 burst quota, the number of lambda function instances would never reach above 1000 because it would be first hitting the limit set by "concurrent executions" quota before getting anywhere near to "Burst concurrency" quota? (Unless I requested AWS to increase my "Concurrent executions" quota)

Comment: The AWS Support Center is probably the best place to ask these questions

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/)